# CakePHP button or submit , and jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->button('A Button');
echo $this->Form->button('Another Button', array('type'=>'button'));
echo $this->Form->button('Reset the Form', array('type'=>'reset'));
echo $this->Form->button('Submit Form', array('type'=>'submit'));
?>
```

Which should i use among them?

I will click a button and the jquery ajax code will be executed.

The whole page will not be reloaded/refreshed.

Only the part of that division will be reloaded and the result getting from database will be displayed .

I have added a division , it's for Poll.

There is a question and four answers.

One can select one radio button and click the button then the result from database will be displayed in that division.

How can i do this with jQuery ajax ?

The jQuery ajax format is like that =>

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

So how can i call an action of a controller with this format ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to reload the page, then go with one of these:

```
echo $this->Form->button('A Button');
echo $this->Form->button('Another Button', array('type'=>'button'));
```

Comment: Ok, i used this, echo $this->Form->button('Check');  , but how can i call an action with jQuery ajax ?

Comment: Add a click event handler to your button in your javascript file, that will prevent the default behaviour of the button, and then execute your ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would probably suggest using an Anchor () tag for that if you're SURE you're not going to actually submit the form.  Those buttons actually call an action on the browser and have more default styling to adjust before they look how you want them to look.

Does CAKE have an Anchor Helper?  Is the code intense?  Just my 2 cents :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to use button not reset or submit to handle it form ajax.
You can use reset button to reset your page.